# How to run cat6 shielded cable from rack

Tags: networking, ethernet, rj-45, cat6

I'm planning on running shielded cat6 cable because Ethernet will travel parallel to power on multiple occasions. The rack and patch panel they are going to will be bounded to ground. A few questions:

#1 Do the internal rack components require shielded cable that connect to the patch panel bonded keystones? (Reminder that patch panel is bonded and the cables patched in are shielded.)

#2 Do the external components (ip camera, switch, wall outlet, etc) require bonding?

#3 If a shielded patched in cable in the rack terminates to a wall outlet with a shielded keystone, does the device connected to that outlet require shielding and perhaps bonded back to ground somehow through a power source or other?

Thank you

Comment: It depends on what you mean by “required?” None of it is required, as in by electrical code. However, the more grounds the better, and both ends of a shielded cable should be grounded. Without a ground on both ends you have essentially created an antenna susceptible to interference from certain RF frequencies. But, in this case it sounds like your concern is about nearby power lines. So run shielded cable where they are parallel with power lines and bond both ends. All other patch cables and devices do not need to be grounded.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have trouble understanding how the wire becomes an antenna if only one end is of the shielded wire is connected to a grounded source instead of both ends. My understanding is that electricity tries to find the shortest path back. With that said, any current on the shield should be sent back to earth right? So how does it become an antenna? Are my metal toasters with a ground also serving as antennas?

Comment: "electricity tries to find the shortest path back" correct but not relevant to this instance. You're trying to prevent electro-magnetic *induction* from mains to nearby ethernet cables.

Comment: Yes, your toaster is also an antennae. Electricity behaves differently when you’re talking about DC or AC currents. You are thinking of this from a DC current perspective. Once you have an AC current moving through a wire, it behaves differently. There is capacitance, impedance, and resonance. You can find a lot of information about this online. I’ll let you do the research. But the best practice, and the recommended configuration that you will see from any Ethernet cable manufacturer is to ground both ends.